# Retrieve class in which variable was instantiated

Tags: java, reflection, java-8, annotations

Is it possible in Java to receive a class, where particular variable was declared?
For example, note this code:

```
class SomeClass {
    private AnotherClass myVariable;
}
```

What I want to do is to receive a class SomeClass inside the AnotherClass. But I could not find any information about this.
If it is not possible, please, inform me.

Comment: What do you mean by _"receive"_? could you maybe show some code of what you think that would look like?

Comment: You are confusing instantiation and variables. Your `SomeClass` *declares* a variable of type `AnotherClass`, but somewhere else, an object of type `AnotherClass` might be *instantiated*, which might then in turn be *assigned* to `myVariable`. Three different things which may happen at three entirely different code locations. Keep in mind that an arbitrary number of variables might refer to the same object instance.

Comment: Do you mean [Field.getDeclaringClass()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getDeclaringClass())?

Comment: Yes, it seems like this is what I was searching.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can access this information directly, but there are indirect ways.

1. If you just want

   > to receive a class SomeClass inside the AnotherClass

   You can make `AnotherClass` an inner class - so Outer class info will be accessible.
2. You can find class `SomeClass` with reflection:
   iterate all classes and find which one has field of class `AnotherClass`.
3. Add an annotation to detect `SomeClass` class directly while iteration all classes

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the comment you can use [Field.getDeclaringClass()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getDeclaringClass()).

But have a look at these classes:

```
class Master {
    private Object o;
}

class Sub extends Master {}
```

In that case `Sub.class.getDeclaredField("o");` would throw `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: o` because `o` is a member of `Master`.

So you need to invoke `Master.class.getDeclaredField("o");` (so you already need to know the declaring class...)